# Login verification using database

Tags: java, database, servlets

When the entered user exists in the database the `if` part of resultset runs but when it doesn't, the `else` part isn't. why?

Here's my code.

```
String thisname=request.getParameter("username");
String thispwd=request.getParameter("password");

//Query for selecting user name and password from database.
String query = "select * from login where username=?";
pstmt = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.setString(1, thisname);
res = pstmt.executeQuery();

while(res.next())
{
    System.out.println("hhh");

    if ((thisname.equals(res.getString("username"))) && (thispwd.equals(res.getString("password"))))
    {
        System.out.println("hello");                                            
    }               
    else
    {
        System.out.println("in");
        session.invalidate();
        response.sendRedirect("index.html");
    }    
}
```

Comment: because `res` has empty result set and `res.next()` returns false. no `while loop` executed

Comment: Consider to use JAAS for authentication and authorization in Servlets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@user1069186: this is because if the entered user does not exists then in that case `res.next()` would always return false and the control will never go inside while. So in your code there is no use of `else` part.

Try to use the below modified code:

```
String thisname=request.getParameter("username");
String thispwd=request.getParameter("password");

//Query for selecting user name and password from database.
String query = "select * from login where username=?";
pstmt = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.setString(1, thisname);
res = pstmt.executeQuery();

if(res.next())
{
    System.out.println("hhh");
    if ((thisname.equals(res.getString("username"))) && (thispwd.equals(res.getString("password"))))
    {
        System.out.println("hello");                                            
    }               
}else {
    System.out.println("in");
    session.invalidate();
    response.sendRedirect("index.html");
}
```

And let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

@SuneetBansal telling right. Otherwise use this method.

```
    String thisname=request.getParameter("username");
    String thispwd=request.getParameter("password");

    //Query for selecting user name and password from database.
    String query = "select * from login where username=?";
    pstmt = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(query);
    pstmt.setString(1, thisname);
    res = pstmt.executeQuery();

    while (res.next()) 
    {
        thisname= res.getString("username");
        thispwd= res.getString("password");
        break;
    }   
res.close();
pstmt.close();
```